Selection Rectangle not moving along with WPF datagrid content during scroll
I am trying to replicate the selection behavior of Windows File Explorer within a WPF DataGrid. Specifically, I aim to implement a selection rectangle that mimics the functionality of File Explorer's selection mechanism.  Currently, I have created an adorner rectangle to facilitate the selection of items. However, I encounter an issue when attempting to select rows while scrolling. As the DataGrid's content scrolls within its own ScrollViewer, the rows that are not intersecting with the selection rectangle are being deselected as the Selection rectangle is static and not moving along with the datagrid content during scroll. Its like the rectangle is in the air and not pasted with the datagrid.  To provide a clearer understanding of the issue, I have included images below for reference.

I have tried multiple solution but nothing worked. I am expecting that this rectangle should move along with datagrid content during scroll as we see in windows file explorer.
  `<DataGrid
             Grid.Row="2"
             x:Name="FileDataGrid"
             HeadersVisibility="Column"
            
             HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
            
             VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
            
             AutoGenerateColumns="False"
            
             CanUserResizeColumns="True"
            
             GridLinesVisibility="None"
            
             IsReadOnly="False"
            
             HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"
            
             PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown="DataGrid_PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown"
            
             PreviewMouseLeftButtonUp="DataGrid_PreviewMouseLeftButtonUp"
            
             RowHeight="25"
            
             Loaded="Grid_Loaded"
            
             PreviewMouseMove="DataGrid_PreviewMouseMove"
            
            ScrollViewer.ScrollChanged="FileDataGrid_ScrollChanged"
            
             SelectionChanged="FileDataGrid_SelectionChanged"
            
            
            
             SelectionMode="Extended">
            
                    
            
                     <DataGrid.CellStyle>
            
                         <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridCell}">
            
                             <Style.Triggers>
            
                                 <Trigger Property="DataGridCell.IsSelected" Value="True">
            
                                     <Setter Property="BorderBrush">
            
                                         <Setter.Value>
            
                                             <SolidColorBrush Color="Transparent" />
            
                                         </Setter.Value>
            
                                     </Setter>
            
                                     <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.ControlTextBrushKey}}" />
            
                                     <Setter Property="Background">
            
                                         <Setter.Value>
            
                                             <SolidColorBrush Color="Yellow" />
            
                                         </Setter.Value>
            
                                     </Setter>
            
                                 </Trigger>
            
                             </Style.Triggers>
            
                         </Style>
            
                     </DataGrid.CellStyle>
            
                     <DataGrid.RowStyle>
            
                         <Style BasedOn="{StaticResource @DataGridRowStyle}" TargetType="DataGridRow">
            
                             <Setter Property="IsHitTestVisible" Value="True" />
            
                             <EventSetter Event="MouseEnter" Handler="DataGridRow_MouseEnter"/>
            
                         </Style>
            
                     </DataGrid.RowStyle>
            
                     <DataGrid.Columns>
            
                         <DataGridTemplateColumn
            
                         x:Name="LeftName"
            
                     
            
                           Width="1.5*"
            
                         MinWidth="180"
            
                         CanUserResize="True"
            
                         CanUserSort="True"
            
                         Header="Name"
            
                         IsReadOnly="False"
            
                         SortMemberPath="Name">
            
                             <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            
                                 <DataTemplate>
            
                                     <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
            
                                         <Image
            
                                         Width="17"
            
                                         Height="17"
            
                                         Margin="15,0,-25,0"
            
                                         HorizontalAlignment="Right"
            
                                         Source="Images/sms-mobile.png" />
            
                                         <TextBlock
            
                                         Margin="35,4,0,0"
            
                                         Text="{Binding Name}"
            
                                         ToolTip="{Binding Folder}" />
            
                                     </StackPanel>
            
                                 </DataTemplate>
            
                             </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            
                             <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
            
                                 <DataTemplate>
            
                                     <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
            
                                         <Image
            
                                         Width="17"
            
                                         Height="17"
            
                                         Margin="15,0,-25,0"
            
                                         HorizontalAlignment="Right"
            
                                         Source="Images/sms-mobile.png" />
            
                                         <TextBox
            
                                         Width="auto"
            
                                         Height="Auto"
            
                                         Margin="35,0,10,0"
            
                                         Padding="0"
            
                                         HorizontalAlignment="Left"
            
                                         VerticalAlignment="Center"
            
                                         BorderBrush="Blue"
            
                                         BorderThickness="1"
            
                                         Loaded="TextBox_Loaded"
            
                                         Text="{Binding Name, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
            
                                     </StackPanel>
            
                                 </DataTemplate>
            
                             </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
            
                         </DataGridTemplateColumn>
            
                         <DataGridTextColumn
            
                         x:Name="sizecolumn"
            
                        MaxWidth="100"
            
                         Binding="{Binding FormattedSize}"
            
                         Header="Size" />
            
                         <DataGridTextColumn
            
                         x:Name="lastModifiedColumn"
            
                       MaxWidth="120"
            
                         Binding="{Binding LastModified}"
            
                         Header="Date Modified " />
            
                     </DataGrid.Columns>      
            
             </DataGrid> 
        
        private void DataGrid_PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
        
        {
        
        
        
          isleftbuttonpressed = true;
        
          isSelecting = true;
        
          selectionStartPoint = e.GetPosition(FileDataGrid);
        
        
        
          adorner = new SelectionAdorner(FileDataGrid, selectionStartPoint);
        
          var adornerLayer = AdornerLayer.GetAdornerLayer(FileDataGrid);
        
          adornerLayer.Add(adorner);
        
          adorner.SetStartPoint(selectionStartPoint);
        }
    private void DataGrid_PreviewMouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    
    {
    
    
    
    if (e.LeftButton == MouseButtonState.Pressed)
    
    {
    
        isleftbuttonpressed = true;
    
      
    
    }
    
    if (isSelecting && adorner != null)
    
    {
    
        adorner.SetEndPoint(e.GetPosition(FileDataGrid));
    
        var selectionRect = adorner.GetSelectionRect();
    
        SelectItemsInRectangle(selectionRect, FileDataGrid, sender, e);
    
    }  
    
     private void SelectItemsInRectangle(Rect selectionRect, DataGrid dataGrid, object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    
    {
    
    
    
     foreach (var item in dataGrid.Items)
    
     {
    
         var row = (DataGridRow)dataGrid.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromItem(item);
    
         if (row != null)
    
         {
    
             var rowBounds = GetRowBoundsRelativeToDataGrid(row, dataGrid);
    
             // Check if the row intersects with the selection rectangle
    
             if (selectionRect.IntersectsWith(rowBounds))
    
             {
    
                 // Select the item and add it to the collection of selected items
    
                 row.IsSelected = true;
    
             }
    
             else
    
             {
    
                 row.IsSelected = false;
    
             }
    
         }
    
     }
    } `


It wont move with the scroll viewer unless you put it inside said scroll viewer. I believe you may need to reimplement your own custom Datagrid Style in order to accomplish this. I would also recommend posting some code examples, and maybe screenshots to further show what you are trying to accomplish. You may want to use a transparent canvas to draw on and then insert that inside the scroll viewer. Then you have to math all the coordinates to find what is selected.

Hi @GingerNinja thanks for replying. I have shared one picture above where you can see the rectangle is floating above the Datagrid when I'm scrolling as only the datagrid rows are scrolling as the rectangle is not the part of the Datagrid, it's a adorner. I tried putting datagrid inside a scrollviewer but with that headers are also scrolling. I will share the code soon. Thanks for your time and see if you can suggest something.

Adoners are not part of the visual tree. They are rendered on top of all WPF controls. This means there is nodirect link between the ScrollViewer and your adorner. You would have to listen to ScrollViewer.ScrollChanged and then update your adorner with the new coordinates and redraw it. You may want to use the viewport of the ScrollViewer as a clip geometry to avoid extra calculations to manually clip your adorner.

Yes @BionicCode adorners are not part of the visual tree. But as you suggested if I redraw the adorner during scroll then it might affect my selection behavior. Can you please check my selection rectangle code once. Will it affect my current selection logic? If it can you suggest some better approach to handle the problem.

The adorner shouldn't affect anything. It should be a simple visual feedback, nothing else. You select items by 1) click down (first selected item + adorner start drawing) 2) mouse move (do nothing except drawing the adorner) 3) mouse up (last selected item + adorner stop drawing) 4) programmatically select all items between first item (mouse down) and last item (mouse up). When you scroll, you only move the adorner (it will appear fixed and scroll with the items). You should not select by coordinates or rectangles etc.

The adorner is just candy to provide visual feedback to the user but without any programmatical relevance.

Hi @BionicCode
But can it handle that case also when we start drawing the adorner rectangle from outside the datagrid, the way windows file explorer behave like we will not press on any item but  start selecting from outside the grid and whenever this rectangle touches the rows it will select all of them. Suppose if we are drawing the adorner from upper right corner from outside the columns and moving our mouse down without selecting anything and in bottom if we touch with any row then all the rows will get selected without a mouse up.

It's all about logic. Let's say you implement the aforementioned raw algorithm. Then when you start outside the viewport you miss step 1). This is a special case that you have to implement. In  this case when 1) is missing you track mouse move and set the first row you enter/hover over as starting row. It can and will get more complex. For example, you move the mouse outside the viewport, you probably want to scroll the viewport to continue selection. The suggested algorithm was just to give you an idea that you should notr focus on the adorner to select items. But on mouse movement.

It's simpler than you thought because you don't have to focus on identifying items by their coordinates. But it's still not too trivial if you want to scroll while dragging etc. But still not complicated. There are different possible approaches. For example, you can set a global flag, a static property, that drag selection has started. Then handle DataGridRow mouse enter event that queries that flag. When it is set, then the row/cell must set itsef to selected. Or you inherit DataGrid to iplement the drag-selection behavior there.

The question remains why you want the rectangle to be visible after the selection operation? The common behavior is that the rectangle only appears to visualize the selected items during the drag. The rectangle usually disappears after the selection operation has completed (mouse up). It will lokk very odd if that rectangle remains visible, don't you agree?

No i am not keeping the rectangle visible after the mouse up event as it will look odd. But i am very new to WPF and i am not getting how to implement your logic. Can you please review my above code and suggest the changes needed.

Is there a reason you are using the outdated .NET Framework 4.7.2? It's been superseded for years now. You should use .NET 8 if possible (at least .NET 6).

Especially the FileInfo and DirectoryInfo API has been improved, which is quite relevant in your case.

Hi @BionicCode can you please suggest some logic how to select items if we start drawing adorner from outside the Datagrid row.

Hi Amit. Please check the following pastebin link for some suggestions: https://pastebin.com/3Wd5jKG7. This will give you an idea so that you can base an estimated effort on it and then decide if it is worth the hassle. The suggested solution is based on my posted answer. You basically add behavior while reusing some of the existing logic and behavior.

Hi @BionicCode can you please check your pastebin account i need some help there.

What do you mean, what must I check?? The Pastebin link isn't working? I can open it.

ohh sorry to bother you, i thought you dont get any notification when someone comment in pastebin. Yes link is working you please check in your free time , i pasted some queries there.

I wasn't receiving any notifications indeed. But now I see you were commenting on the file. I wasn' logged in when creating the  document hence it is not linked to my account and I was not receiving any notifications.

I suggest to comment on the GitHub link from my answer. Create an issue  there so I can get notified. Please mmove your questions to GitHub. It's easier to communicate.

On Github I can even directly comment on your code lines.

In short, when on auto-scroll, you must select rows by index. The vertical scroll ofsset obtained from the ScrollViewer is also the item index (IF ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll is TRUE as mentioned in my notes).

Also don't use a Dictionary. Use a HashSet. You don't need to store the index. GetRowIndex is too expensive and redundant. You don't need to lookup rows by index. You only need the HashSet to lookup already selected rows. That's all. If the HashSet alreaady contains the row then this means that the mouse has changed direction and requires to unselect rows.

Or use a Stack and a HashSet. The Stack to track the selection sequence in their original order (this way direction does not matter) and the HashSet to track general selection (fast lookup). It's even better in this scenario:

DataGridRow.MouseEnter scenario: 1) IF mouse is pressed AND mouse enters the row AND that row IS NOT contained in the HashSet THEN select the row and add it to the HashSet and push it to the Stack. 2) Next case: IF mouse is pressed AND mouse enters the row AND that row IS contained in the HashSet THEN mouse revisits that row which means we have to unselect the previously visited row: pop the last item from the Stack (Stack.Pop) and also remove it from the HashSet and unselect it.

The next item on the Stack is the current item. If the mouse continues to move on and enters the previous row case 2) will repeat and the current row will get unselected.

DataGridRow.MouseLeave scenario: not required! Because of the Stack we don't need mouse leave. We can gracefully unselect on mouse enter.

Next behavior: auto-scroll. ScrollContentPresenter.MouseEnter scenario: IF mouse is pressed THEN stop the DispatcherTimer. ScrollContentPresenter.MouseLEave scenario: IF mouse is pressed start DispatcherTimer e.g. not faster than 500ms interval. DispatcherTimer executes the OnAutoScrollTimerElapsed callback.

OnAutoScrollTimerElapsed callback: get the ScrolViewer that you have stored in a readonly field and obtained from within the OnApplyTemplate override (see my answer). Get  ScrollViewer.VerticalOffset and add 1 and store the result in a local newVerticalOffset variable. Then call ScrollViewer.ScrollToVerticalOffset and pass in newVerticalOffset.

Continue and call DragSelectDataGrid.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromIndex using the newVerticalOffset as index. Select the returned DataGridRow by setting IsSelected to TRUE and by pushing it onto the Stack and by adding it to the HashSet.

Don't forget to always check if CanContentScroll is TRUE before using ScrollViewer.VerticalOffset or ScrolViewer.ScrollToVerticalOffset. If ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll returns false you must throw an exception (e.g. InvalidOperationException). It's crucial that CanContenScroll returns TRUE in order to be able to scroll by item index. Otherwise you would have to calculate the pixels to scroll. As mentioned already you must first get the CanContentScroll==TRUE use case to work. Then add support for the pixel-based CanContentScroll==FALSE use case. Step-by-step.

Finally, you must override the OnItemsSourceChanged virtual method. Because when the source collection has changed you must clear the Stack and the HashSet. Same applies to the OnSelectionChanged override. Inside this method you check if DragSelectDataGrid.SelectedItems is empty. If TRUE then clear the Stack and the HashSet. You may also have to check if there are new items added to the SelectedItems collection (use the SelectionChangedEventArgs object to know what items were removed and added.

The point is that the DragSelectDataGrid can be modified programmatically by client code e.g. by explicitly adding/removing items to/from the SelectedItems collection. If those are new external changes (they are external when they were not tracked by the DragSelectDataGrid) then update the Stack and HashSet accordingly.

Next step is to implement the correct behavior when the user completes selection (releasing the mouse button) and then starts a new drag select operation from outside the DragSelectDataGrid. You now have to unselect selected item But I guess you don't need to think about that right now. First get the "user starts a new drag select from outside the DragSelectDataGrid" use case going.

Since the DataGrid already supports multi-select using mouse press + mouse move you only have to handle the adorner clipping to the scrollable area (ScrollContentPresenter).
I suggest extending DataGrid and move the adorner handling to this custom DataGrid.
See the full example including a fixed FileExplorer (there were some bugs in your tree structure) at GitHub: DataGrid_Drag_Select_Example.
This is just raw code. You likely have to improve the behavior in terms of bugs and you want to prettify the look. However, the example is usable and a good starting point.
Adorner.cs
public partial class SelectionAdorner : Adorner
{
  public Brush SelectionBrush { get; set; }
  private Point startPoint;
  private Point endPoint;

  public SelectionAdorner(UIElement adornedElement)
    : base(adornedElement)
  {
    this.startPoint = new Point(0, 0);
    this.endPoint = new Point(0, 0);
    this.IsHitTestVisible = false;

    this.SelectionBrush = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.LightBlue) 
    { 
      Opacity = 0.5 
    };
    this.SelectionBrush.Freeze();
  }

  protected override void OnRender(DrawingContext drawingContext)
  {
    Rect clippingBounds = LayoutInformation.GetLayoutSlot((FrameworkElement)this.AdornedElement);

    Point coercedStartPoint = clippingBounds.Contains(this.startPoint) ? this.startPoint : ClipLocation(this.startPoint);
    Point coercedEndPoint = clippingBounds.Contains(this.endPoint) ? this.endPoint : ClipLocation(this.endPoint);
    var rectangle = new Rect(coercedStartPoint, coercedEndPoint);
    drawingContext.DrawRectangle(this.SelectionBrush, null, rectangle);
  }

  public void SetStartPoint(Point point)
  {
    this.startPoint = point;
    this.startPoint = ClipLocation(this.startPoint);

    InvalidateVisual();
  }

  public void SetEndPoint(Point point)
  {
    this.endPoint = point;
    this.endPoint = ClipLocation(this.endPoint);

    InvalidateVisual();
  }

  public void Move(double horizontalOffset, double verticalOffset)
  {
    this.startPoint.Offset(horizontalOffset, verticalOffset);
    InvalidateVisual();
  }

  // Clip new location:
  // Y = 0 < location_Y < adorned_element_height
  // X = 0 < location_X < adorned_element_width
  private Point ClipLocation(Point point)
  {
    double horizontalOffset = point.X;
    double coercedHorizontalOffset = Math.Min(Math.Max(0, horizontalOffset), ((FrameworkElement)this.AdornedElement).ActualWidth);

    double verticalOffset = point.Y;
    double coercedVerticalOffset = Math.Min(Math.Max(0, verticalOffset), ((FrameworkElement)this.AdornedElement).ActualHeight);

    return new Point(coercedHorizontalOffset, coercedVerticalOffset);
  }
}

DragSelectDataGrid.cs
public class DragSelectDataGrid : DataGrid
{
  private SelectionAdorner selectionAdorner;
  private AdornerLayer adornerLayer;
  private double actualRowHeight;
  private ScrollViewer scrollViewer;
  private ScrollContentPresenter scrollContentPresenter;
  private bool canPerfromDragSelect;

  public DragSelectDataGrid()
  {
    this.Loaded += OnLoaded;
    this.canPerfromDragSelect = true;
  }

  private void OnLoaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
  {
    this.adornerLayer = AdornerLayer.GetAdornerLayer(this);
    if (this.adornerLayer == null)
    {
      throw new InvalidOperationException("No AdornerDecorator found in the parent tree.");
    }
  }

  public override void OnApplyTemplate()
  {
    base.OnApplyTemplate();
    if (!TryFindVisualChild(this, out this.scrollViewer))
    {
      throw new InvalidOperationException("No ScrollViewer found");
    }

    this.scrollViewer.ScrollChanged += OnScrollChanged;
    if (!scrollViewer.IsLoaded)
    {
      this.scrollViewer.Loaded += OnScrollViewerLoaded;
    }
    else
    {
      EnsureScrollContentPresenter();
    }
  }

  protected override void OnLoadingRow(DataGridRowEventArgs e)
  {
    base.OnLoadingRow(e);
    if (e.Row.ActualHeight == 0 || this.actualRowHeight == 0)
    {
      return;
    }

    // Get the lates row height. Row height is relevant when CanContentScroll is TRUE
    // in order to convert the actual scroll offset from item to pixel.
    this.actualRowHeight = e.Row.ActualHeight;
  }

  protected override void OnBeginningEdit(DataGridBeginningEditEventArgs e)
  {
    base.OnBeginningEdit(e);
    this.canPerfromDragSelect = false;
  }

  protected override void OnCellEditEnding(DataGridCellEditEndingEventArgs e)
  {
    base.OnCellEditEnding(e);
    this.canPerfromDragSelect = true;
  }

  private void OnScrollViewerLoaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    => EnsureScrollContentPresenter();

  private void EnsureScrollContentPresenter()
  {
    if (!TryFindVisualChild(this.scrollViewer, out this.scrollContentPresenter))
    {
      throw new InvalidOperationException("No valid ScrollViewer found");
    }

    this.scrollContentPresenter.PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown += OnPreviewMouseLeftButtonDown;
    this.scrollContentPresenter.PreviewMouseMove += OnPreviewMouseMove;
    this.scrollContentPresenter.PreviewMouseLeftButtonUp += OnPreviewMouseLeftButtonUp;

    this.selectionAdorner = new SelectionAdorner(this.scrollContentPresenter);
  }

  private void OnScrollChanged(object sender, ScrollChangedEventArgs e)
  {
    bool canContentScroll = ScrollViewer.GetCanContentScroll(this);
    double verticalOffset = canContentScroll
      ? this.actualRowHeight * e.VerticalChange
      : e.VerticalChange;

    double horizontalOffset = e.HorizontalChange;

    this.selectionAdorner?.Move(-horizontalOffset, -verticalOffset);
  }

  private void OnPreviewMouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
  {
    // For example, do not perform a select while any row is in edit mode
    if (!this.canPerfromDragSelect)
    {
      return;
    }

    // Get the current row height and store it as it usually won't change.
    // Row height is relevant when CanContentScroll is TRUE
    // in order to convert the actual scroll offset from scrolled items to scrolled pixels.
    if (this.HasItems)
    {
      FrameworkElement rowItemContainer;

      bool canContentScroll = ScrollViewer.GetCanContentScroll(this);
      if (canContentScroll)
      {
        int rowItemContainerIndex = (int)this.scrollViewer.VerticalOffset;
        rowItemContainer = (FrameworkElement)this.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromIndex(rowItemContainerIndex);
      }
      else
      {
        rowItemContainer = GetFirstVisibleIndex();
      }

      this.actualRowHeight = rowItemContainer?.ActualHeight ?? 0;
    }

    Point selectionStartPoint = e.GetPosition(this.scrollContentPresenter);
    this.selectionAdorner.SetStartPoint(selectionStartPoint);
    this.selectionAdorner.SetEndPoint(selectionStartPoint);
    this.adornerLayer.Add(this.selectionAdorner);
  }

  private FrameworkElement GetFirstVisibleIndex()
  {
    for (int itemIndex = 0; itemIndex < this.Items.Count; itemIndex++)
    {
      var rowItemContainer = (FrameworkElement)this.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromIndex(itemIndex);
      if (rowItemContainer != null)
      {
        return rowItemContainer;
      }
    }

    return null;
  }

  private void OnPreviewMouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
  {
    base.OnPreviewMouseMove(e);
    if (e.LeftButton != MouseButtonState.Pressed)
    {
      return;
    }

    Point selectionEndPoint = e.GetPosition(this.scrollContentPresenter);
    this.selectionAdorner.SetEndPoint(selectionEndPoint);
  }

  private void OnPreviewMouseLeftButtonUp(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
  {
    base.OnPreviewMouseLeftButtonUp(e);
    this.adornerLayer.Remove(this.selectionAdorner);
  }

  private bool TryFindVisualChild<TChild>(DependencyObject parent, out TChild child)
    where TChild : DependencyObject
  {
    child = null;

    if (parent is Popup popup)
    {
      parent = popup.Child;
    }

    if (parent == null)
    {
      return false;
    }

    for (int childElementIndex = 0; childElementIndex < VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(parent); childElementIndex++)
    {
      DependencyObject childElement = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(parent, childElementIndex);
      if (childElement is TChild resultChildElement)
      {
        child = resultChildElement;

        return true;
      }

      if (TryFindVisualChild(childElement, out child))
      {
        return true;
      }
    }

    return false;
  }
}


Thanks for the solution. I will try it and let you know.

Hi @BionicCode i tried drawing selection rectangle from outside the grid and selecting the items using that rectangle but its not happening. can you please suggest what changes are needed in the current code to achieve that functionality.

Here we are using the Datagrid internal support for multiselect but that works only if we start selecting from any row. Is there any way we can use this functionality if we start pressing from outside the grid and then entering in the grid using mouse move.
